# Function returns "application not procedure" error instead of new list

Tags: scheme

I am trying to write a function that takes a list of structs and makes a new list using one of the attributes of each struct.

I have successfully written a similar function that takes a list and returns a new containing each item

Here is the function I currently have

```
(define makelist
  (lambda (items part)
    (if (null? (cdr items)) (invItem-id (car items))
        (cons (invItem-id (car items)) (makelist ((cdr items) part))))))
```

I know the part does nothing, but I plan to add a cond to the function to check what part is passed so it knows what attribute to get. Later I pass an already defined list called "inventory" using this function 
`(makelist (inventory "id"))`

After running I get this error

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: (#<invItem> #<invItem> #<invItem> #<invItem> #<invItem> #<invItem> #<invItem>)
  arguments...:
```

although I would expect to just get a new list containing the id of each invItem in inventory. Something like (1 2 3 4 5 6 . 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(makelist ((cdr items) part))` should be `(makelist (cdr items) part)`.

Also `if (null? (cdr items)) (invItem-id (car items))` should be `if (null? items) '()` so that the result will always be a proper list.

I would recommend using `(map invItem-id items)`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I updated my function the way you described and I also realized my call `(makelist (inventory "id"))` was wrong thanks to your recommendations. It now works